# Verify the authentication of sales achievement with Benford's law

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am practicing to verify the authenticity of the planet largest shopping celebrity- "Double 11" of Alibaba.

First to draw a benford graph

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results drawer
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
# fig = fig(figsize=(20.00, 6.18))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)


def benford(n):
    return log10(n+1) - log10(n)

results = [benford(i) for i in range(1, 10)]
ax1.bar(list(range(1,10)), results)

# create benford bar graph
index = np.arange(1, 10)
ax1.bar(index, results)
ax1.plot(index, results)
# ax1.xticks(index, index)
plt.show()
#+end_src
```

[image]

Second to plot the sales by year

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results drawer
# data, unit: ten million RMB
sales_by_year = {"2009":"5.0",
         "2010":"93.6",
         "2011":"520",
         "2012":"1910",
         "2013":"3500",
         "2014":"5710",
         "2015":"9120",
         "2016":"12070",
         "2018":"21350",
         "2019":"26840"}
count = {}

for k, v in sales_by_year.items():
    idx = v[0]
    if idx not in count:
        count[idx] = 1
    else:
        count[idx] += 1

count = {k:v/10 for k, v in count.items()}

sales = [0 for i in range(9)]

for k, v in count.items():
    sales[int(k)-1] = v

ax2.bar(index, sales)
ax2.plot(index, sales)
# ax2.xticks(index, index)
fig
#+end_src
```

[image]

The side-by-side graphs tell that they do not fit with each very well.

However, the judgement is by human sense.

How could figure out how many they are fitted, saying "0.01%" or "0.002"?

Comment: you want how much they overlap or have similarity sort of thing??

Comment: yes, how much similarity. @Vicrobot

Comment: I don't think you can do it with this data, you'd need the individual amounts (not aggregated to annual totals) to get anywhere

Comment: or any tools which do the job of predict the fitting of two graph? @SamMason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is just a draw from a multinomial distribution, parameterised by probabilities from Benford's law.  Using scipy you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

benford = np.log10(1 + 1/np.arange(1, 10))
counts = [2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2]

stats.chisquare(counts, benford*sum(counts))
```

and get a p-value of 6.9%, which doesn't reject at the standard 5% level.  I'm also not sure how reliable this test is with these low counts, the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) suggest that values should be >5, which your values certainly aren't.